# Suppose $f(x) > 0, f'(x) > 0,$ and $f''(x) >0.$ Then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Intuitively I see why this is true, in terms of a graph, but I can't seem to get a handle on a proof. I know that I need to show for every $M > 0$ there's a $d > 0$ such that whenever $x > d$, $f(x) > M.$ I attempted proceeding by contradiction, but wasn't able to make much progress. I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Fix some $a$. From $f''(x)>0$, conclude that $f'(x)>f'(a)$ for $x>a$. Then conclude that $f(x)>f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)$ for $x>a$. For both steps, you can use the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'$ is increasing we get $f(x)=f(1)+\int_1^{x} f'(t)dt \geq f(1)+(x-1)f'(1) \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Prove that $f(n+1)-f(n)\ge f'(0)$.

*Remark:* The condition that $f(x)>0$ is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b=f(0)$ and $m=f'(0)$.  Then $f(x)>mx+b$ for all positive $x$ (since $f$ is concave up everywhere), so you can find a $d$ for any $M$ from that easily.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's expansion with Lagrange's remainder we have that for some $c\in (x_0,x)$

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac12 f''(c)(x-x_0)^2 \ge f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0) \to \infty$$